# Multiple recipients of interprocess event (.NET)

Tags: .net, windows, events, ipc

I have for ex. 3 processes, everyone of which can fire a predefined event. All these processes should listen for this event and execute code only once (per new event), reset the event and wait for it to fire again. So, for each event there should be 3 actions run. The processes aren't started by 1 initial process. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use AsyncCallback Delegate for this. Check it out;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.asynccallback(v=vs.110).aspx

---

basically you can use like that with your event:

```
AsyncCallback finish= new AsyncCallback(EndThis);
Delegate1 delege = new Delegate1(Function1);

delege.BeginInvoke(finish, delege);
```

and write this method:

```
void EndThis(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            if (result.IsCompleted)
            {
                Delegate1 dlg = result.AsyncState as Delegate1;
                dlg.EndInvoke(result);
            }
        }
```

But i suggest you to use Threads for that, its easier. Here is an example for 3 process can fire same time with an event. I use button click event but you can use in your own.

Put 3 listviews and 2 buttons and try yourself. I hope this can help you

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AsyncCallbackDelegate
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        }

        void Func1()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 377885; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(i);
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
            }
        }

        void Func2()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i += 3)
            {
                listBox2.Items.Add(i);
                listBox2.SelectedIndex = listBox2.Items.Count - 1;
            }
        }

        void Func3()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 50000; i ++)
            {
                listBox3.Items.Add(i);
                listBox3.SelectedIndex = listBox3.Items.Count - 1;
            }
        }

        Thread t1;
        Thread t2;
        Thread t3;

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ThreadStart ts1 = new ThreadStart(Func1);
            ThreadStart ts2 = new ThreadStart(Func2);
            ThreadStart ts3 = new ThreadStart(Func3);
            t1 = new Thread(ts1);
            t2 = new Thread(ts2);
            t3 = new Thread(ts3);
            t1.Start();
            t2.Start();
            t3.Start();

        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            t1.Abort();
            t2.Abort();
            t3.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Isn't AsyncCallback only for thread communication in a single process?

Comment: I don't need threads, i need Processes! Your delegate won't work between processes